# Google Analytics API login required error

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, analytics

I've got a strange problem that I've tried to solve but I've tried a whole day and it just doesn't work, so I hope maybe someone else can help me with this.

I've build a CMS and after you login you see the dashboard.
On this dashboard you can click on a button to connect your account with Google - because I want my customers to be able to connect their Google Analytics account.

Everything works fine, I've got tokens and the refresh token and everything seems to work. Even when I request my user profile data I get it printed on my screen as an array. But when I try to get the accounts that are available to view for the connected user i get this error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties
key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: (401) Login Required'
```

I just don't understand why I get the message 'Login required'.
Below you can see my script.

```
require_once('/Google/Client.php');
require_once('/Google/Service/Analytics.php');

// call object
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Analytics - CMS title");
$client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes(array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics'
));

// decode
$token = $token; // this comes from my database and it's json encoded

// connect
$client->setAccessToken($token);

// call service
$service    =   new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

// get accounts from analytics
$accounts   = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
```

When I try to var_dump $accounts I don't see anything because the error already occurred (Login required)

I think you are going to ask me now if my token is correct but it is because I tested it with other api calls.. it's just not working for this specific analytics request.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks,
Pim vd Molen

UPDATE:
Something really strange just happened. I don't know how this is possible but the error just changed into another error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET 
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management
/accounts?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: (403) Access Not Configured. 
Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

I've enabled the Google Analytics service ofcourse, but don't know which one i also need to enable.

Comment: Did you try unsetting the token?

unset($_SESSION['token']);

Comment: Thanks for your reply nickspiel. unsetting the session is not necessary because that session doesn't even exist (i var_dumped ($_SESSION) ..after i connected i did put the token in my database and thats where i get it from every page reload)

Answer (score 1):

The 401 error [clearly](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization#helpme) states that the credentials are wrong. The Token might be valid for retrieving Data, but for retrieving user management information, you need a particular grant when asking for that token, please look [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization#auth) in the table you see the additional value for the `scope` parameter to set in your OAuth request.

Comment: Hello axel, thanks for your reply.
I checked my scopes and added everything that could be missing but it still doesn't work. When i go to https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and i add exactly the same scopes en request url then i get the data i need.. so it's working in the playground but not in my cms.

Comment: plz reply, i am facing same issue like Pim vd Molen

Comment: `401`= `401` = credentials wrong. Google is not lying on error messages. Check your request: did you url-encode the credentials? If so, remove, they are plain ascii!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you have solved this yet, but I've documented the process, with photos here:
https://circlical.squarespace.com/blog/2014/7/18/getting-zend-framework-2-and-googles-api-to-play-nice